# Updating a text widget using onchanged

Tags: flutter

I am trying to update a text widget as the user types, its working but i don't see the input as I type

```
         TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            controller: amountController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            cursorColor: Colors.amber,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Amount",
                prefixIcon: Material(
                  elevation: 0,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.phone_outlined,
                    size: 15,
                    color: Color(0xff020529),
                  ),
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 13)),
            onChanged: (value) {
              add(value);
            },
          ),
```

this is the widget

```
       Text( x.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
```

This is my method

```
  add(String value) {
   var ans = 36 * double.parse(value);
  print('ddd');
  setState(() {
   x = ans;
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a gif/video of the issue?

Comment: As per your request, i have added the gif

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is `double.parse` is failing because the given value can't be converted to a number.
One option to handle this is by using a try catch (see following code sample), and then setting the displayed value to 0 (or could also do something like set an error message saying something like "invalid input" if the user enters something like "123d"

```dart
add(String value) {
  double ans;
  try {
    ans = 36 * double.parse(value);
  } on FormatException catch (e) {
    // string couldn't be formatted to double
    ans = 0;
  }
  setState(() {
    x = ans;
  });
}
```

I used a try catch, but you could also check if `value` is empty, and/or add an `onError` callback to `double.parse`.

Comment: The input even disappears even when I call only set State inside the textformfield

Comment: @Godwin Are you making any changes to your amountController? Specifically are you changing the text property of it?

Comment: No, am just picking the controller ad multiplying it with constant and then updating the widget